# How to Generate dynamic HTML form (add a new row on-click of button) & retrieve data in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

> I want to generate multiple row (inside a HTML form), on-clicking of add-Row button. Actually I am posting snippet of code, in reality my HTML Form is more complex. A row has 2 input box, 4 select options (2nd and 4th select option is dependant on 1st and 3rd). **My code is working fine, But how can i retrieve these values in angular controller. I want to access my html form data inside angular controller.**

```
<div class="addcontend">
       <div ng-repeat="item in inputs">
         <input ng-model="item.value"\>
         <select ng-model="item.parentselection"> 
            <option>opt 1</option>
            <option>opt 1</option> 
         </select>
       </div>
</div>

  $scope.inputs = [];
  $scope.addfield=function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({})
  }
```

> How do I map my html-form DATA to angular $scope. So that I can have a single object array.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Ok, the scenario is like. I have  a page where by default a html form will b there (in a single row there will be 2 input box and 4 selection box). there is button called "add-new-row". on clicking button it will replicate the html form & create another row (2 input box and 4 selection box).
I am able to do this through my code, but the problem is- I am not able to figure it out "How do I access the values of html form in angular controller"
because when I generate html form dynamically, it is replicating same code, it is replicating model name also. how do I map my html form data to $scope

Comment: I got it. Here it is
https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevs/oyb644jc/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can simply loop through the scope to get the values eg.

```
 angular.forEach($scope.inputs, function (value, key) {   
      // get values here
 });
```

to get the last object in the object array for the last item you pushed in the array you can do

```
$lastObject = $scope.inputs[$scope.inputs.length-1]
```